# Native keyboard input for Ctrl+ü

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard

The physical layout of my keyboard is a German one. However, for Windows I'm using a custom keyboard layout created with the [Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339).
Within that layout I defined <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> to be `{`. It's working fine almost everywhere, with the major exception being the Mathematica front-end. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> in the front-end only produces a beep. The "Why the Beep?" window message is

> You used a Command or Control key combination that is not defined to do anything.

[image: Snipped]

Is there a way to make Mathematica input the symbol that is natively defined by the keyboard layout whenever there is no keyboard shortcut defined for that key combination within Mathematica?

I'm mainly looking for some kind of setting that activates such a behavior. I'm not interested in adding a keyboard shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> to *KeyEventTranslations.tr* (neither in the `$InstallationDirectory`, nor in the `$UserBaseDirectory`) that inputs `{`. If there is no better way, a command I can add for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> to *KeyEventTranslations.tr* that makes Mathematica input the symbol that is native for the currently used keyboard layout, would be interesting too.