# Using an umlaut for a keyboard shortcut

Tags: front-end, customization, keyboard

How can I define a keyboard shortcut based on an umlaut like ü?

`KeyEvent` in *KeyEventTranslations.tr* doesn't seem to register umlaut based keyboard inputs.
For example, after adding

```
Item[KeyEvent["ü", Modifiers -> {Control}], FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "{", After]]],
Item[KeyEvent["\[UDoubleDot]", Modifiers -> {Control}], FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "{", After]]],
Item[KeyEvent[\[UDoubleDot], Modifiers -> {Control}], FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "{", After]]],
Item[KeyEvent["ü", Modifiers -> {Command}], FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "}", After]]],
```

to *KeyEventTranslations.tr* pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd> in the front-end (using a German keyboard layout) only produces a beep. The message in the "Why the Beep?" window states

> You used a Command or Control key combination that is not defined to do anything.

However, adding

```
Item[KeyEvent["+", Modifiers -> {Control}], FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[FrontEnd`InputNotebook[], "}", After]]],
```

does work as expected.
Also the `EventHandler` does understand umlaut based key events correctly, e.g.,

```
DynamicModule[{col = Green}, 
 EventHandler[Style["text", FontColor -> Dynamic[col]], 
  {{"KeyDown", "ü"} :> (col = col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}]]
```

Is it completely impossible to have keyboard shortcuts in Mathematica that are based on umlaut? Or is there another key code one has to input into `KeyEvent` instead of `"ü"` or `"\[UDoubleDot]"`?

Comment: Maybe you can do it the hard way, using low level (like OS or driver) API.

Comment: @Silvia I tried it the OS way (creating a custom keyboard layout), but it doesn't work inside the front-end. Hence I asked [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126737/native-keyboard-input-for-ctrl%C3%BC) previously. All the `[`, `{`, `}`, and `]` are like yoga for the right hand on a German keyboard.

Comment: hmm... have you tried simulating a USB keyboard by directly writing to certain USB port? That way no one will realize it's a fake. I'm on mobile phone so not easy to post a link, but as a start you can try searching USBPcap.

Comment: @Silvia Thanks for that hint. USBPcap is supported by [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org), which I had to update anyway. I'll try it out over the weekend. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Please do let me know if it works!